# How to execute a keyboard macro until termination inside another one, without stopping the recording?

Tags: keyboard-macros

I have a buffer with the following content and I need to delete the duplicate lines.

```
57,04/15/2020 03:02PM,'Weight'='2.478 lb','tare'='0.918 lb'
57,04/15/2020 03:02PM,'Weight'='2.478 lb','tare'='0.918 lb'
57,04/15/2020 03:02PM,'Weight'='2.478 lb','tare'='0.918 lb'
57,04/15/2020 03:02PM,'Weight'='2.478 lb','tare'='0.918 lb'
57,04/15/2020 03:02PM,'Weight'='2.478 lb','tare'='0.918 lb'
58,04/15/2020 03:03PM,'Weight'='2.441 ','tare'='0.969 '
58,04/15/2020 03:03PM,'Weight'='2.441 ','tare'='0.969 '
58,04/15/2020 03:03PM,'Weight'='2.441 ','tare'='0.969 '
58,04/15/2020 03:03PM,'Weight'='2.441 ','tare'='0.969 '
59,04/15/2020 03:03PM,'Weight'='2.452 kg','tare'='0.517 kg'
59,04/15/2020 03:03PM,'Weight'='2.452 kg','tare'='0.517 kg'
60,04/15/2020 03:04PM,'Weight'='2.403 lb','tare'='0.526 lb'
60,04/15/2020 03:04PM,'Weight'='2.403 lb','tare'='0.526 lb'
60,04/15/2020 03:04PM,'Weight'='2.403 lb','tare'='0.526 lb'
60,04/15/2020 03:04PM,'Weight'='2.403 lb','tare'='0.526 lb'
61,04/15/2020 03:04PM,'Weight'='2.497 kg','tare'='0.738 kg'
61,04/15/2020 03:04PM,'Weight'='2.497 kg','tare'='0.738 kg'
61,04/15/2020 03:04PM,'Weight'='2.497 kg','tare'='0.738 kg'
61,04/15/2020 03:04PM,'Weight'='2.497 kg','tare'='0.738 kg'
62,04/15/2020 03:05PM,'Weight'='2.47 ','tare'='0.625 '
62,04/15/2020 03:05PM,'Weight'='2.47 ','tare'='0.625 '
62,04/15/2020 03:05PM,'Weight'='2.47 ','tare'='0.625 '
62,04/15/2020 03:05PM,'Weight'='2.47 ','tare'='0.625 '
63,04/15/2020 03:05PM,'Weight'='2.425 lb','tare'='0.515 lb'
63,04/15/2020 03:05PM,'Weight'='2.425 lb','tare'='0.515 lb'
63,04/15/2020 03:05PM,'Weight'='2.425 lb','tare'='0.515 lb'
63,04/15/2020 03:05PM,'Weight'='2.425 lb','tare'='0.515 lb'
63,04/15/2020 03:05PM,'Weight'='2.425 lb','tare'='0.515 lb'
64,04/15/2020 03:06PM,'Weight'='2.431 oz','tare'='0.703 oz'
64,04/15/2020 03:06PM,'Weight'='2.431 oz','tare'='0.703 oz'
64,04/15/2020 03:06PM,'Weight'='2.431 oz','tare'='0.703 oz'
64,04/15/2020 03:06PM,'Weight'='2.431 oz','tare'='0.703 oz'
```

For this I was thinking of using 2 keyboard macros. The first one starts with `57,` in the kill ring, searches for the next occurrence of the piece of strings and deletes the line. This keyboard macro I saved as `del`

```
(fset 'del
   (lambda (&optional arg) "Keyboard macro." (interactive "p") (kmacro-exec-ring-item (quote ([19 25 return 11 11] 0 "%d")) arg)))
```

The second keyboard macro encompasses the first one. It starts on line 0, column 0. It sets the marker and searches for the next `,` and copies the string (so you have `57,`), and I enter `M-0 M-x del` to invoke the first one until it doesn't find `57,` anymore. This deletes all the lines starting with `57,`

```
(setq last-kbd-macro
   [?\C-  ?\C-s ?, C-return ?\M-w ?\M-0 ?\M-x ?d ?e ?l return])
```

However the termination condition of the first keyboard macro also stops with recording of the second one. How to keep the recording open?

For now, it isn't a problem, but what if I want to add some other stuff after deleting all the same lines? I know there is `kmacro-edit-macro`, can it also be done without this and during the recording?

Comment: I have no answer for the general question of interacting macros, but for the particular problem at hand (deleting duplicate lines), I would recommend marking the region and then running `M-x shell-command-on-region RET uniq RET` and after verifying that it does what you expect, doing the same thing but with a `C-u` prefix to replace the region with the output of the command.

Comment: @NickD thank you for your suggestion. I did not know `uniq` and never userd `shell-command-on-region`. Yet another thing to get familiar with. However I would like an answer on my question to keep recording. I provided my example situation for context, -and for possible other solutions proposed like yours.

Comment: Understood. BTW, `uniq` is a Unix command - do `man uniq` at a shell prompt to read its manual page and find out how to use it. The main point of my comment above is that there are tools *outside* of emacs that can be used to solve problems *within* emacs.

Comment: There is also `M-x delete-duplicate-lines`, @NickD.